# JavaScript - Fire event when innerHTML or attributes change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found a jQuery calendar that has the ability to scroll through months and I would like to fire an event every time the month changes so I can add event listeners to every td element in the table (the days are td elements). The only way that I have seen to do this is check to see when the month has changed. Is there an event that will fire whenever the innerHTML or "data-month" attribute changes? Thanks for the help. FYI, if you know an easier way, the calendar I am using is located here: https://github.com/philipehsing/jQuery.Simple-Event-Calendar/archive/master.zip

```
<h2 class="month" data-month="12">December 2015</h2>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

there are these buttons with class btn-next and btn-prev. try to work with its click event.

if the dom element that holds the month gets updated, one of these elements had been clicked.

Comment: This is what i initially had in mind. however, the event listener will fire before the content changes (the td elements). So, i am adding event listeners to the current td elements, then the month changes and wipes out the registered listeners. If that makes sense.

Comment: i do not know in wich direction EventListeners are called and that they are not chaining but a bad practice solution that could help is to set a timeout in your self defined click listeners. like `on('click', function() { setTimeout(function() { /* your code */ }, 1);});`

Answer (score 0):

Just add event listeners (maybe `onclick`) to the next and back buttons. Also, if the user change change the input field without using these buttons, then add an event listener (`onchange` maybe) to these fields.